# How can I use LaTeX-commands inside of a listing?

Tags: listings

I'm using the listings package in a LaTeX document. It works great, but it doesn't allow me to put LaTeX commands inside of the listing. I would like to use a counter to enumerate some of the interesting parts in the source code.

Is there a way to enable LaTeX commands in source listings?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

OK, found the answer. You can use `escapechar=<char>` to set a character that will escape you to the latex mode. See [The Listings Package, 4.3.13 Escaping to LaTeX](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: Is there a default? I couldn't find it quickly. From what I understand there is no default.

Comment: Here is an example: if you set `escapechar=\%`, you could use it inside the listings as follows: `\begin{lstlisting} t %\leftarrow% 0 \end{lstlisting}`.