# LaTeX - Using commands inside inline code

Tags: listings, inline

I want to be able to have inline code (printed in typewriter or something) where I can also use LaTeX commands like `\myinlinecode{here comes a backslash: <\textbackslash>}`. So it should be possible to use non-verbatim parts inside the code command.

I [read](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26579/how-can-i-use-latex-commands-inside-of-a-listing) that it should be possible with the `listings` package but I could't get it to work. What I tried was:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{escapebegin=x, escapeend=y}
\lstinline|x\textbraceleft y|

\lstset{escapebegin={x}, escapeend={y}}
\lstinline_x\textbraceleft y_

\lstset{escapebegin={\textbackslash}, escapeend={\textbackslash}}
\lstinline_\\textbraceleft \_

\end{document}
```

Comment: AFAIK `listings`' possibilities for escaping to LaTeX are only available for the environment and not for the inline command. Do you _need_ verbatim? Otherwise there's  of course `\texttt{}`...

Comment: Judging from the `listings` manual, the answer in the linked question seems to be incorrect. The correct key should be `escapechar`, or `escapeinside`.

Comment: @T. Verron both work fine for me with \lstlisting but I couldn't get them to work with \lstinline. I also couldn't get escapebegin to work like you said not even with \lstlisting so I upvoted your comment in the linked question.

Comment: See also [Escaping in \lstinline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43526/escaping-in-lstinline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following syntax makes it easier to use "escaped" (or LaTeX) content within `\lstinline`, and might be what you're after. There seems to be no particular need to use specially-assigned characters (like `x` and `y`) and the usual `mathescape` option works (escaping between `$`...`$`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\lstset{mathescape,basicstyle=\ttfamily}% Allow escaping to LaTeX inside $..$
\begin{document}

\lstinline|x$\lbrace$y|

\lstinline_x$\mbox{\textbraceleft}$y_

\lstinline!x{$\partial$}y!
\end{document}
```