# Use textit in listing

Tags: listings, italic

How can I use `\textit` in a listing?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=test]
Some code.
\textit{This should be italic.}
Some code.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Use the `mathescape` option, then inside your `lstlisting` you can use `$\textit{Hello World.}$`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Escaping in `\lstinline`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43526/5764) (since it also applies to `lstlisting`); [Using commands inside inline code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111978/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can emphasize words using the `emph` and `emphstyle` keys.
See page 19 in the [listings manual](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{emph={world}, emphstyle=\itshape} % the word "world" shall be italic
\begin{lstlisting}[label=test]
   Hello world
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I agree, it is not a good solution for highlighting single lines of code.
I think [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/how-can-i-highlight-some-lines-from-source-code) is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=test]
Some code.
(*@\textit{This should be italic.}@*)
Some code.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks :-). But I just want to have one sentence in italic. Rest should be normal.