# Escape to LaTeX from within lstinline

Tags: listings

I'm trying to run a LaTeX command within an `lstinline` from the `listings` package. I found [How can I use LaTeX-commands inside of a listing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26579/how-can-i-use-latex-commands-inside-of-a-listing) which explains about `escapechar`, and I can get that to work with a regular `lstlisting` environment, but `lstinline` seems to ignore it. Am I doing something wrong, is there another way to escape into LaTeX from `lstinline`, or do inline listings just not support it? The [documentation](https://latex.ugent.be/files/documenten/listings.pdf) doesn't seem to address it one way or the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\asdf}{command worked}
\begin{document}
\section{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@]
test: @\asdf@
\end{lstlisting}
\section{lstinline}
\lstinline[escapechar=@]|test: @\asdf@|
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137390/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wow, that title is pretty much exactly what I googled :(. Thanks